# Windows licensing dilemma: Technet to Retail same version upgrade?

Tags: windows-7, licensing

I have a bunch of computers that are running technet Win 7 Pro licenses (intended to be evaluation only, but fully functional). These machines need to "go legit" in the near future.  Can I use an $89.99 "Anytime Upgrade" key to go legit, upgrading from Win 7 Pro (Technet) to Win 7 Pro (Legit)?

http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/en_US/pd/productID.228663600/parentCategoryID.44066700/categoryID.50726200/list.true

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the [technet EULA](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/cc294422.aspx) prohibits you from doing so. Additionally, the [W7 EULA](http://download.microsoft.com/Documents/UseTerms/Windows%207_Home%20Premium_English_a0cdb148-2381-47cd-bfc9-9b9102e0cb28.pdf) section 16b states:

> Windows Anytime Upgrade License. If you upgrade the software using
>   Windows Anytime Upgrade, your proof of license is the proof of license
>   for the software you upgraded from, your Windows Anytime Upgrade
>   product key and your proof of purchase. Proof of purchase may be
>   subject to verification by your merchant’s records.

Assuming your technet reseller does not prohibit you from doing so, there is **nothing** that **explicitly prohibits** you from upgrading a technet license to a full version.

Though, there is nothing that explicitly states that the anytime license **will** upgrade the technet version. Your mileage may vary.